# Can telepathy work on a person in past

Tags: telepathy

Is it possible to communicate with a person in past using telepathy? Or telepathy is a space time bound  communication?

Comment: Surely it is up to you how the magic in your fictional setting works. Time travel is a risky thing to add, if you like coherent stories.

Comment: Thank you.. was trying to understand limitations of telepathy to use in my story which involves time travel.

Comment: OK, the issue is perhaps question phrasing. Is your question about how it _should_ be limited, so as to avoid paradoxes? Or about what sort of paradoxes it could cause? Or something else?

Comment: You've not defined what telepathy is in the context of your world - and, for that matter, whether causality works the same way as it does in ours.  As it stands, the answer can trivially be "yes" or "no" depending on how _you_ define telepathy.

Comment: I'm voting to close because, in its current form, the question is too broad and is definitely opinion-based. @rajesh_Gujjuka, the short answer to your question as phrased would be "it's up to you". Even asking if you *should* allow it is pretty opinion-based, and would in any case need more details about what you are trying to accomplish. What you *might* be able to ask is whether or not it makes sense given some set of constraints on how your telepathy and/or time travel works.

Comment: FWIW, the answer in the Doctor Who universe is apparently "yes", while if you were asking about "reality as-is except where necessarily otherwise", I would expect the answer to be "no". (That said, if it's *one way* telepathy, that's not much different from "past life memories", which is more likely to get a plausibility pass.)

Comment: This is an excellent question!  I don't see how it can't be worldbuilding related, because it is clearly a problem dealing with the nature of an invented world.  This question shouldn't be closed; though I do think @rajesh_Gujjuka ought to give some more detail about how this world works. This should help with the charges of it being opinion based.

Comment: @elemtilas, I think the policy police have closed this one because it is asking about possibility, which is inherently opinion-based when dealing with fictional worlds.  Change the question to ask about the plausibility or believability of such telepathy would move us away from arguing about the existence of a fictional ability in a fictional world, to discussing the ramifications that such an ability would have in the fictional world.  Paradox avoidance and the management of resultingly overpowered characters who have the ability is the kind of meat we are allowed to sink our teeth into here.

Comment: @elemtilas, what Henry said. As currently worded, the question is far too open-ended. With more information/constraints, perhaps it can be reopened. (Even if it had been [tag:science-based], that might have been different, though in that case the answer would be an open-and-shut "no".)

Comment: @Matthew, how certain are we of that open-and-shut "no"?  Applying Occam's razor, which is more likely?  That somewhere within our 3 lbs of grey matter, there is a memory storage mechanism capable of storing, in a losey manner, the entire sensory & cognitive contents of a human lifetime.  Or that somewhere within that same miraculous biological complexity, a single circuit has the ability to reach across time, again with varying levels of clarity, to sample the earlier contents of that same mind at an earlier time.  Memory might be temporal telepathy, limited to a single person conversation.

Comment: @HenryTaylor - I don't disagree. Though twould be nice if we didn't have to argue about the possibility of something fictional in a fictional world here in a forum whose stated goal is making fictional worlds and the fictional things in them. We really need to move ourselves away from complaining about "opinion based" queries because, in the end, every query leads to opinion based responses. Except the maths questions. But even then...

Answer (score 2):

Telepathy is always problematic in fiction. But to answer your specific question, it probably does not matter the exact mechanism, telepathy with another individual in the past is a no-go.

If we imagined the communication between brains was mediated with traditional radiation on the EM spectrum, then there is a speed of light delay between the two people. This might allow for closed timeline curve telepathy-into-the-past... but the telepathy itself wouldn't be special in those circumstances. You could also make phone-calls-into-the-past and so forth. And these circumstances are very rare and difficult to engineer.

Changing the mediation mechanism to more exotic forms of radiation mostly doesn't fix this. Whether you want to fire gluons or mesons or any other particle between the two brains, these particles also obey the speed of light. You might find it interesting to read up on some theoretical particles like tachyons which don't obey the speed of light, but these are at present impossible to confirm and in some cases may violate the Standard Model (supposing that's important to you).

Nor can you allow for this assuming some novel physics or fantasy mechanisms and have anything like a consistent plot point.

Why, for instance, would a telepath reading the mind of a person 100 years ago, read those thoughts in the correct order? If your brain goes through thoughts a, b, and c in that sequence at about 800 milliseconds between each, then a telepath standing next to you will get those in the same order, with the same delay between each.

But if he is reading the mind of a person 100 years ago, and he somehow latches onto thought a, why would he next latch onto thought b next? Why couldn't he come back a day later and catch thought b? Does he have the capacity to choose from which time he reads minds? Does he have the precision to get thought b, which manifested for a fraction of a second at an exact time 100 years ago? If he has no precision (or little), then they will be a jumble, coming out of sequence (or not at all, as he next latches onto some caveman 50,000 years before his target). This probably resembles an intrusive exoschizophrenia more it resembles telepathy.

If he has high precision, then he has a weak form of omniscience, where he can know anything any other human has previously known, supposing he can identify the individual and a point in their life past which they knew it.

And why would this not work for reading minds in the future? Even supposing it only works on humans and not other sapients (perhaps due to details of the human's meat brain), then it becomes an even stronger form of omniscience. By skipping across minds as fast as he himself can target them, he can know nearly anything (as long as some human once knew it, or in the stronger form, if any human will ever know it). By violating causality he can know facts from future people, then cause those people to never be born. He can influence which people are born, and what they learn in the future, allowing himself to then know it before they learned it. He could, hypothetically, invent new fields of science by becoming rich and offering million dollar scholarships and fellowships, learning those things, and then never bothering to spend the money for the field of science to be invented/discovered.

It's difficult to imagine a mechanism that allows for arbitrary mind-reading-in-the-past that can't be twisted to allow for the more absurd implications.