# How can telepathic communication work across different time periods?

Tags: time, telepathy

Gods inhabit a realm parallel to the mortal plane known as the warp. These beings are effectively made up of warp energy condensed into solidified form. They can enter the mortal plane through an avatar, which is a human manifestation of the god imbued with its essence. A god can have multiple avatars at once, with its essence distributed among each of them. As these avatars represent the same being, they can communicate telepathically, sharing information, details, and experiences with each other. Avatars are created through a process of reincarnation, in which they born into the mortal world directly to experience the lives of mortals. A deity known as Azathoth seeks to the mortal plane in a single avatar within the present day. However, the process goes awry, distributing itself across hundreds of avatars across various time periods. This has resulted in many incarnations throughout history, leading to the mocking nickname of Azathoth by other deities as " The Blind Idiot God".

Each avatar has landed at a different point in history all over the world, from Ancient Egypt, to Europe in the Middle Ages, to the industrial revolution, to even the present day. As he is distributed so broadly across the time stream, he is unable to bring his full power to bear on the mortal world. However, the avatars are still able to communicate with each other regardless of where in time they landed. Those who landed in the past can communicate with avatars landing in the future, and vice versa. This shouldn't be possible without a time machine, or some mechanic that allows one to travel through time directly. This doesn't appear to be the case, as telepathic communication occurs instantaneously. The past shouldn't be able to reach out telepathically to the future because it hasn't happened yet, and the future shouldn't be able to talk to the past because it no longer exists.

How can this be possible?

Answer (score 4):

**TL:DR Spoiler alert, frame challenge at the end.**

It's possible because that's the way it is.

The same as Asimov's positronic brain.

The Op states clearly that the gods operate in another dimension, or plane. Leave it at that.

Consider Plato's Cave. Shadows that live in a two dimensional plane. They can not communicate with anything in another plane in the third dimension (depth) without going into another plane, or dimension - the third. But a person who lives in three dimensions can communicate through the third dimension, no problem, without having to move.

Consider time as merely the 'vehicle' to go from one dimension space to another. Everything 'exists' at the same 'time' between all dimensions, except that us poor humans only perceive in three dimensions. In order for us to experience another dimension, we have to 'move' there through time. But a being that lived in more dimensions would already be there, and does not need 'time' to move between them.

Consider a being that lives in a two dimensional plane. To get to another plane to perceive what is happening in that plane, they have to move there, through time. That person can not perceive everything in a three dimensional cube except by going through time. However, a being that can perceive in  three dimensions can perceive things in all of the planes (dimensions) in that cube without going through time.

Now consider that there is a universe of many, many three dimensional cubes, with dimensions w, x, y, and z. On any one cube, dimensions x, y, and z are all available 'at the same time'. A being on that cube can look in any of the x, y, and z directions and equally perceive what is there. But to go to another cube, the w dimension, to perceive what is in the x, y, and z dimensions on that cube requires time. The person can now see in the x, y, and z dimension on that cube, but can not see what was in the previous w dimension cube.

But a being that lives/perceives in four dimensions can perceive what is in the x, y, and z dimensions of all of the cubes in the w dimension at the same time. However, now, its awareness is distributed over more 'territory', and thus 'less aware' in any one cube.

So, if you have followed so far, one last abstract. The fourth dimension is, in fact, time. The w dimension is all of those three dimensional cubes, through all history. Humans perceive these cubes sequentially, as if they happen one after the other, but a four-dimensional being can perceive them all at once. The four-dimensional being does not need to move between these separate cubes, this being experiences all of them 'at once'.

The down side of this, is that it presumes the entire existence across all time is predetermined. Nothing about it can be changed or altered, because it already exists. If the 'future' cube in time exists at the same time as the 'past' cube in time, they are both absolutely determined. Each cube has determined every other cube, both forward and backwards in time. That is, they are all the same fourth dimensional existence.

Kind of boring for a being that 'knows' what has, is, and will happen, without any potential for drama, suspense, or change.

Answer (score 3):

## Time is like a river.

From a mortal perspective, event y follows event x in a logical fashion. From a divine perspective, outside in the warp, the two events are just both part of the river of time.

Azathoth can swim in the river like any mortal, and will generally be pulled along with the current unless they are able to exert their full power, but they can see the truth of reality, and can call out to others of their kind.

## Rivers twist and turn.

Mortals are trapped under the surface of the river, unable to see the nature of reality. Just as a two dimensional square could not comprehend a cube, a mortal cannot comprehend time. Azathoth can see it all, and can sense when others of his kind are close, calling out to them. While the river's distance may be too great for his weakened power to reach out along it's length, he can sense the connections and places where aspects of time are close, and call out to his fellows as though they were meters away.

Careful placement of bodies is needed to keep the flow of messages. An avatar may need to stay near a historically potent event, or messages would be lost. With his full power this would be no issue, but he is far from fully powered.

## Rivers are part of a cycle.

Like a river, time will eventually meet it's end, and return to the source. Azathoth can comprehend both ends, from the big bang to the time when the dream that reality is ends, and can understand how some objects will flow faster than others. If one is trapped, unable to reach their companions, they can simply toss a message down the river, letting it flow from the end to the beginning faster than they can move.

It is hard to predict which of their kind it will hit, but with enough cycles they can likely contact another avatar and seek freedom.

Comment: Just watch out for the Langoliers, however.

Answer (score 2):

If we consider that the 'Warp' may be a parallel universe with its own flow of time, this may be possible, though such an occurrence would have its own limitations.

First we must consider the nature of telepathy between avatars: effectively an avatar has a thought, which is witnessed by the avatar's deity, and from there the other avatars become privy to that thought, as each avatar exists within the deity's attention and control simultaneously.

Consider that Azathoth causes many avatars to be incarnated simultaneously, from his point of view from the Warp.  However, each ends up at a different point in time in our own universe.  However, measuring time from the birth of the avatars, Azathoth is still witnessing and controlling each of the avatars *simultaneously* from his point of view.  Each avatar at a given age is in telepathic contact with each other avatar *at the same age*.  From the point of view of the avatars, each might as well be living on another world since they can never physically come in contact with each other, however they can communicate.

Now, realistically, Azathoth may not create the avatars simultaneously... let's say that from his point of view from the Warp, he creates one each month.  Let's say that he creates 100 avatars.  So, the youngest avatar at an age of *n* would have a telepathic link to the oldest avatar at its age of *n*+100 months.  Aside from the fact that the avatars are living in different ages, to Azathoth, their lives are experienced running in parallel.

While not having many avatars existing simultaneously in our universe may be limiting to Azathoth in some ways, it would have its own advantages too.  Azathoth's avatars, seen from within our universe, would appear to be gaining in power as time went on.  The first would be virtually powerless, but might be uncannily lucky.  The last would have access to vast reserves of goods and wealth.  How could this be?

If we consider that Azathoth's first avatar in our universe would live out their life with minimal powers compared to the avatars of other gods, how might they be lucky?  By being a diarist.  By keeping a diary, the avatar can communicate with the future avatars.  At some point in the future, another avatar obtains these diaries and reads them, and uses telepathy to inform the past avatar of critical points in its life.

As an example, let's say that someone tries to murder the first avatar.  A future avatar reads in First's diary that First escaped an attempted murder on a particular day.  Using telepathy, Future can inform First that on that day, First must beware of a person with a particular appearance in a particular place and time.  The warning is sufficient for First to avoid being knifed in the back... perhaps seemingly by luck, or supernatural senses.  First dutifully writes this in their diary after the fact... which Future can read...

Similarly, an avatar may be able to look at history, and suggest to past avatars what to do...  Invest in Apple and Microsoft.  Don't be in Hiroshima on August 6, 1945.  Little things like that...

Going the other way, future avatars have the advantage of being able to capitalise on the good fortune of their predecessors.  Future needs quick cash?  They can just dig up a cache of gold left by a past avatar in a seemingly ridiculous location.  Being pursued unarmed through an old part of town?  They could find an old gun behind a loose brick.
The possibilities are endless.

Finally, Azathoth's avatars could shape history.  Make a change, and see what that change might have.  Put poison in a leader's food, and see what would follow.   If bad, remove it,  if good, leave it.

Answer (score 2):

## Each Avatar is in a different parallel universe set in a different historical period, but actually experiencing only one time:

This answer is based on a question I had asked about how to treat [time as a multi-dimensional object](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/176601/is-three-dimensional-time-consistent-and-paradox-free-for-time-dimension-travele). Your god, coming from outside our universe, is constrained by different rules and relates to our universe differently. It's natural it got confused. The universe is a three-dimensional time object as well as a three-dimensional physical object. NOW is one of those dimensions, like a flat plane, but past and future can exist in additional dimensions (we think of them as parallel universes, but that's only because we can't understand three-dimensional time).

Other gods that have manifested in the world with multiple avatars manifested them in a single point of three-dimensional time but multiple points of three-dimensional space. Your god manifested multiple avatars in one point in space, but multiple points of three-dimensional time.

All points of history exist simultaneously in another plane (sheet) of three-dimensional time-space. So while your god SEEMS to be in different times, he's actually just spread out over multiple different NOW points but in a different (NOW) sheet set at a 45-degree angle to "normal" historical time.

This also means that because the other points of "NOW" the god is touching aren't in a straight line but instead are in a sheet, that alterations to the "timeline" don't affect the other (later) avatars. It would also mean the god would have no previously recorded avatars, because in linear (timeline) time, the god didn't have any avatars. All avatars will be in contact with their "selves" at the same age, since they all "started" at the same NOW.

Answer (score 0):

I have a previous answer for "telepahy across time" [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/168534/can-telepathy-work-on-a-person-in-past/168540#168540).

The gist of it is that it's nonsense.

> Why, for instance, would a telepath reading the mind of a person 100 years ago, read those thoughts in the correct order? If your brain goes through thoughts a, b, and c in that sequence at about 800 milliseconds between each, then a telepath standing next to you will get those in the same order, with the same delay between each.

> But if he is reading the mind of a person 100 years ago, and he somehow latches onto thought a, why would he next latch onto thought b next? Why couldn't he come back a day later and catch thought b? Does he have the capacity to choose from which time he reads minds? Does he have the precision to get thought b, which manifested for a fraction of a second at an exact time 100 years ago? If he has no precision (or little), then they will be a jumble, coming out of sequence (or not at all, as he next latches onto some caveman 50,000 years before his target). This probably resembles an intrusive exoschizophrenia more it resembles telepathy.

> [...]

> It's difficult to imagine a mechanism that allows for arbitrary mind-reading-in-the-past that can't be twisted to allow for the more absurd implications.